# Excel/VBA - Transpose column to row leaving set spaces between records

Tags: vba, excel

What I am trying to do is take a column of data and transpose it into a single header row, but space out each record such that 'Sheet1'A1 -> 'Sheet2'B1, 'Sheet1'A2 -> 'Sheet2'G1 and so on.  (i.e. spaced out every 5 columns)

I am brand new so I was playing around with a loop such that:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
i = 1
j = 1

Do While i < 200
Cells(1, i + 1).Value = "='Project List'!A1"
i = i + 5
j = j + 1
Loop
```

I was trying to use the Int 'j' as a way to cursor through the cell reference in "='Project List'!A1" but can't seem to find a way to do it.  I attempted recording a macro but it was using the FormulaR1C1 = "='Project List'!RC[-1]" format and I couldn't figure out how step through R1C1 references either.  The 200 was an arbitrary number so that I would capture the whole list of projects, I'm still trying to find a "repeat to blank" style of reference.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to step through my column of data? Loop? Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks,
Dane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are tons of ways to do this but yours is a viable method with some slight modifications. You should create Worksheet objects to reference your input and output worksheets. My code also implements the repeat til blank logic you requested. As you can see, I commented out the first of the outWS lines. Either of those two lines will do the job. Keep the formula one if you need the values to update dynamically. Otherwise use the other one. Obviously you can change Book7.xlsm and Sheet2 as needed. You can also swap `Workbooks("Book7.xlsm")` for `ThisWorkbook` if the code is in the same spreadsheet as the data.

```
Sub transposeAndSpace()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim inWS As Worksheet, outWS As Worksheet
    i = 1
    j = 1
    Set inWS = Workbooks("Book7.xlsm").Worksheets("Project List")
    Set outWS = Workbooks("Book7.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Do While inWS.Cells(j, 1).Value <> ""
        'outWS.Cells(1, i + 1).Formula = "='Project List'!A" & j
        outWS.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = inWS.Cells(j, 1).Value
        i = i + 5
        j = j + 1
    Loop

    Set inWS = Nothing
    Set inWS2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect!  I should have guessed that I could have used & to join together the string for the cell reference with 'j'.  The static reference would work great as I use a command button to kick off a macro that this is a part of.  Thanks!
(btw, what is the significance of clearing the inWS/outWS at the end?)

Comment: @DaneMeister Those lines release the references for those worksheet objects allowing the memory to be disposed of. Good practice to avoid memory leaks. In reality though, Excel *should* release those on its own when the variables leave scope so in many cases (like this one) they aren't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Do/While loop is working for you:

```
i = 1
j = 1
Do While i < 200
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, i + 1).Value = "='Project List'!" & Range("A1").Offset(,j).Address
    i = i + 5
    j = j + 1
Loop
```

When i & j = 1, this should yield:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, i + 1).Value -->  Sheet2.Range("B1").Value
```

And it will put the formula:

```
"='Project List'!$A$1`
```

When i = 6, j = 2, should yield:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, i + 1).Value -->  Sheet2.Range("G1").Value
```

And it will put the formula:

```
"='Project List'!$A$2`
```

etc.